# How to Inject dynamic object in response class of @ApiOperation for Swagger

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Am developing a project to handle CRUD operation for 50+ entities using Spring boot REST api with Swagger documentation.

For all the CRUD operation i have a common response which can handle `GET`,`UPDATE`,`POST` and `DELETE`.

Am using `@ApiOperation` as shown below for swagger documentation, Below is just an example for Client entity,

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Client details API", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            httpMethod = "GET", response = InternalApiResponse.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, message = HttpStatusMessages.MESSAGE_200),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, message = HttpStatusMessages.MESSAGE_401),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN, message = HttpStatusMessages.MESSAGE_403),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND, message = HttpStatusMessages.MESSAGE_404) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<InternalApiResponse> getClients(@ModelAttribute RequestParams requestParams,
            @ModelAttribute Client client) throws InternalApiException {

    }
```

InternalApiResponse.class is as shown,

```
InternalApiResponse.class
{
  private Status status;

  private Error error;

  private Object entityObject;
}
```

in the above class, entityObject needs to be dynamically considered based on input entity (ex: `@ModelAttribute` Client client)

Swagger UI is as shown :
[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPFdJ.png)

From Java side i can inject required object in response at run time, But how i can inject the required object to **InternalApiResponse** for Swagger `@ApiOperation`, so that can i see the Api response with particular entity details in Swagger UI...Please help

Comment: did you find a way? like asm etc